# Can't update a component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a usual crud application in `React`. You can add a party to the list and each party list item can be edit, deleted etc. Currently, I am working on the grey + button which should increment the votes by 1 each time the button gets clicked.

UI of the application

[image]

However, as soon as I click the button, the application breaks with the following error code.

Error Code

[image]

I am trying to update a component using `setState()`, but its not working. I thought somebody might help. I have been trying for 3 days, but nothing works. I have to admit that I am a beginner.

Here is a link to the current code .

https://github.com/Benni8753/Election2021.git

Thanks in advance.

Benjamin

Comment: The issue comes from line 44 in ElectionDashBoard.jsx, when you're mapping that array, if it matches when you do `aParty.votes++` it's returning the votes instead of the aParty object, so when you click it the first time, it converts it from the object to a number. So when you go to click the button the second time, it attempts to access `number.votes`

Comment: As @Rodentman87 mentioned , the error is line 44 of `ElectionDashBoard.jsx`. This line `aParty.id === partyId ? aParty.votes++ : aParty` if the IDs match, you should be setting it to **an object, whose 'votes' property has been incremented**. E.g. `aParty.id === partyId ? { ...aParty, votes: aParty.votes + 1} : aParty`

Comment: OMG it works! Thank you very much :) . It is much appreciated.